# Slicing photoshop image into a HTML5 + CSS3 button (issue with the corners)

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am trying to slice a .psd image of a button into a HTML5 + CSS3 button. But I don't want just to set it as background. I want to slice 1 repeating tile for the background and 4 corners, so the button expands correctly, according to its content. Can someone give me a basic idea how to place the corners? I searched in the forum, but noone slices the button, they just put the whole image as background. Thats what I have so far:

EDIT: I have one tile repeating as background, and 4 images of the whole 4 corners.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercise1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exercise1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div><a href="">OK</a></div>
    <div><a href="">Cancel</a></div>
    <div><a href="">View More Information</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {

    background-color: black;
}

a {

    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 13px;
    background: url(pictures/background_tile.png) repeat-x center top;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

And that's how I am trying to put the corners, but it gets all messed up:

```
div {
    background: url(pictures/btn_top_left.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I cant give a fiddle link, but I cant find any uploaded pictures of sliced buttons, so I can't really set up an example

Comment: Link to your images with an absolute url on your server

Comment: The problem is I don't have a server :/ But I will upload them somewher in a few minutes to set up a quick example ;)

Comment: [Here's a link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFcN4/) . And here are the images:

[background](http://i43.tinypic.com/2zgem49.gif)
[top-left-corner](http://i43.tinypic.com/5xifdg.gif)
[tor-right-corner](http://i43.tinypic.com/2vn0sk6.gif)
[bottom-left-corner](http://i42.tinypic.com/dninnl.gif)
[bottom-right-corner](http://i42.tinypic.com/2yjskde.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the gist of it, you'll need to fix the right side AND slice the buttons more accurately. Also, these don't expand on height, only width. If you want height, then make the corners taller, 3-4 times as tall and play around with it. No one does this these days, you can make buttons that look identical-enough using css3.

**http://jsfiddle.net/26tWC/**

```
<ul class="button">
     <li class="tl">&nbsp;</td>
        <li class="text"><a href="">Button Text</a></li>
        <li class="tr">&nbsp;</li>
     <li class="bl">&nbsp;</li>
     <li class="br">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>



<ul class="button">
     <li class="tl">&nbsp;</td>
        <li class="text"><a href="">Longer Text Goes Here</a></li>
        <li class="tr">&nbsp;</li>
     <li class="bl">&nbsp;</li>
     <li class="br">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>


body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family:arial;
}

.button {
    height:48px;margin:0;padding:0 38px 0 19px;
    list-style:none;white-space:nowrap;position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
}

.button .text {
    background: url(http://i43.tinypic.com/2zgem49.gif) repeat-x center top;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
}

.button a {text-decoration:none;color:#000;}

.button li {position:absolute;}

.button .text {float:left;height:47px;position:relative;}

.tl {
    width:19px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:24px;
    background: url(http://i43.tinypic.com/5xifdg.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.bl {
    width:19px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:24px;
    background: url(http://oi42.tinypic.com/dninnl.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}



.tr {
    width:38px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:24px;
    background: url(http://oi43.tinypic.com/2vn0sk6.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}


.br {
    width:38px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height:24px;
    background: url(http://oi42.tinypic.com/2yjskde.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

---

Use these tools to make this in CSS3:

http://css3generator.com/

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#fdffff+0,e6f8fd+21,c8eefb+54,bee4f8+75,b1d8f5+100;Custom

Comment: I am pretty good with CSS3 already, but I am now taking programming lessons and our task is to create this button. I know its hard, slowly loading and generally nonsense, but I need to learn it anyways.

Comment: I haven't done these in 5-6 years and there was a lot of spans and shit before. Also, the padding:0 0 0 16px could be removed and just put a width on that :before

Comment: I see there is no enough space for the right corners, but how do I give them. I can't set exact width as they are supposed to resize according to their contents...

Comment: The right corners are using the :after and it's absolute positioned based on the variable width of the contents. Works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/gemLD/ you need to place in the correct images. It's the content that expands, not the corners. If you need content that expands height, then you will need to provide correctly, accurately sliced images that are 3 x tall and the rounded in the appropriate x y cordinates.

Comment: I did already on my computer. But the right corners are not fully visible. When I set bigger width on the :after they are visible, but they get pushed to the left and the button gets messed up :(

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I see that you need to actually enter in the precise image widths and adjust the padding and various things to make it work. Here's something closer, but your image slice was not good.http://jsfiddle.net/aNDAy/